# Is there any way to restric access to REST endpoint based on caller port?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, port

There is a Spring Boot app running on a host, it exposes number of REST endpoints. One of these endpoints is providing sensitive information.

On the same host resides a client app, over which I have no control.

1 - Is there any way using Spring Security to limit access to the endpoint in question, based on client's port?

I cannot change anything in the client app, since it is a 3rd party app.

2 - is there any other way to limit access based on ports, like iptables rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it seems like it is not possible to limit access to endpoint based on the port of the caller, only using Spring Security.

[Spring Security Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html5/#el-access-web)

1 - However, using Spring Security one can limit access, based on the IP that the request is made - [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html5/#el-access-web).

2 - Also one can get the `HttpServletRequest request` object in the controller method and get the port that the request is made from, like:

```
request.getRemotePort();
//IP is also available
//request.getRemoteAddr();
```

=> in the end what I need is doable.